# How do you do Proper case in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Good day,
how to set values to Proper/Title case? 
in SQLite.

for each example:

```
value:
THIS IS A SAMPLE
THIS-IS-A-SAMPLE
this is a sample
```

Desired Output:

```
This Is A Sample
This-Is-A-Sample
This Is A Sample
```

Comment: There are no words in either proper or title case in your example.

Comment: I Edit it so that you will see the desired output. the examples are the following and the desired output should be the proper/title case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy built-in mechanism to do this.

It is possible to write a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to convert the strings char by char:

```
WITH RECURSIVE pcase(id, rest, result) AS (
  SELECT ID,
         Name,
         ''
  FROM MyTable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id,
         substr(rest, 2),
         result || CASE WHEN substr(result, -1) GLOB '[A-Za-z]'
                        THEN lower(substr(rest, 1, 1))
                        ELSE upper(substr(rest, 1, 1))
                   END
  FROM pcase
  WHERE rest <> ''
)
SELECT id,
       result
FROM pcase
WHERE rest = '';
```

(The ID is not required.)

However, it would be a better idea to create a user-defined SQL function in whatever language you are accessing the database from.

Comment: what a creative way to do that.

Comment: It's ugly, but, by gum, it works!